# Link to document properties/metadata in SharePoint 2013 Designer document approval workflow

Tags: 2013, 2016, metadata, sharepoint-designer-workflow

My company is using SharePoint 2016 on premise. I used SharePoint Designer 2103 to build a document approval workflow. The workflow sends an email note to the members of a SharePoint group when a user checks in a major version of a document. The email note contains a link that opens the document and a link that takes the user to the document approval task, and all of that works correctly. I have now been asked to add a link to the email note that takes the approver to a page that displays the document metadata (please see attached "document metadata dialog" image) BEFORE the initiate the approval. Is that possible?

[image: document metadata dialog]

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely. The forms that show the list of metadata are the Display Form (read-only, when you "view properties") and the Edit Form (editable, as in your screen shot).

You can construct the correct URL to that form in your workflow. In your question, you are calling your screenshot the "document metadata **dialog**", so I am assuming you have your library set to open forms in a dialog. That may be the behavior you ultimately want to keep, but if you want to see how the URLs are constructed, you can go into your library settings, advanced settings, and set "Launch forms in a dialog" to No:

[image: screenshot of list settings]

and then go and "view properties" or "edit properties" for one of your documents, and then look at the address bar.

You will see that for the Display Form, the URL is

```
<Your site URL>/Lists/YourLibraryName/Forms/DispForm.aspx?ID=<the ID of the document>
```

and for the Edit Form, the URL is

```
<Your site URL>/Lists/YourLibraryName/Forms/EditForm.aspx?ID=<the ID of the document>
```

So, you can construct either of those URLs in your workflow.  You can get the site URL from the workflow context:

[image: screenshot of workflow lookup]

Getting the site URL that way includes a trailing slash, so you don't need to add one between that and `Lists/`.  Choose which form you want to direct people to, construct the URL to that form, and then add the ID of the current item as the `ID` query parameter:

```
[%Workflow Context:Current Site URL%]Lists/YourLibraryName/Forms/DispForm.aspx?ID=[%Current Item:ID%]
```

or

```
[%Workflow Context:Current Site URL%]Lists/YourLibraryName/Forms/EditForm.aspx?ID=[%Current Item:ID%]
```

and then use that URL in the link in your email.

Comment: Thanks Dylan. This is exactly what I needed! now I just need to figure out how to indicate that your response answered my question

Comment: @Frank near the top of my answer, just to the left, there is a big zero with up and down arrows (upvote and downvote buttons), and just below that should be a checkmark that you can click on to check this as the accepted answer.